# How to print list of unicode in Python3

Tags: python, unicode

How do you "just print" a list containing unicode in Python3?

In Python2.*, I could simply do:

```
text = ['\u2014']
print(text)
```

But in Python3, this fails with the notorious error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2014' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Unfortunately, the normal recommendations to use `str()` fail because this only works with bytes in Python3, not lists:

```
>>> print(str(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
TypeError: coercing to str: need a bytes-like object, list found
```

Comment: How did it not work? https://repl.it/Hx2H , it seems fine when running the code from repl.it

Comment: The first question to ask is why your stdout is ASCII. Look into changing your locale to use UTF-8. But if ASCII is your only choice, you can set the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=:backslashreplace`.

Comment: @eryksun, Please submit an answer as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Feel free to write and accept your own answer.

Comment: @eryksun, Why the passive aggressiveness? I'm trying to help you out and give you credit. Just use the site as intended and submit an answer.

Comment: @Cerin, I meant it literally, not in any passive aggressive way. If my comment was useful to you, it's fine by me if you incorporate it in an answer, and I don't care about credit. I commented to help you, person to person, because I was already here, not because the problem interests me.

Answer (score 1):

To get equivalent behavior to Python 2 for printing lists in Python 3, use `ascii()`:

```
>>> text = ['\u2014']
>>> print(ascii(text))
['\u2014']
```